# how to show error when send multipart/form-data in header

Tags: php, laravel, multipartform-data, laravel-10, php-8.2

when add a product to my app,
I check if property "is_force", user should add all required properties to request.
but when sent with multipart/form-data header and if user does not send all required properties in the output just show number "1". and not created product.

*output error*

[image: output error]

but when send with application/json and comment image and gallery validation in request show me correct form of validation error.

*Comment Requests*
[image: comment request]

*correct form error*
[image: correct form error]

**Controller**:

```php
 public function storeForSeller(AddSellerProductRequest $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {

        $uploaded = UploaderHelper::upload($request->file('image'), config('path.product'));
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->findById($request->category_id);

        $result = $this->productPropertyRepository->checkPropertyValidation($request->properties(null));

        if(!$result){
            return ControllerHelper::errorJsonResponse(trans('admin.invalid_property_items'));
        }

        $product = $this->productRepository->create($request->product([
            'image' => $uploaded ,
            'expire_date' => Carbon::now()->addDays($category->listing_duration),
            'user_id' => auth('sanctum')->id()
        ]));

        if (empty($product)) {
           UploaderHelper::delete($uploaded);
           return ControllerHelper::createError();
        }

        $this->productTagRepository->replaceTags($request->tags(), $product->id, auth('sanctum')->id());
        $this->productPropertyRepository->createAll($request->properties($product->id));

        $galleries = collect($request->galleries())->map(function ($item) use ($product){
            return [
                'title' => $product->title,
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'url' => UploaderHelper::upload($item, config('path.product')),
                'updater' => auth('sanctum')->id()
            ];
        });

        $result =  $this->productGalleryRepository->insert($galleries->toArray());

        if(!$result){
           UploaderHelper::delete($uploaded);
           $this->productRepository->deleteById($product->id);
           return ControllerHelper::errorJsonResponse(trans('admin.error_image_upload'));
        }

        return ControllerHelper::successJsonData($product);
    }
```

**Request**:

```php
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => ['nullable', 'numeric', Rule::exists('products', 'id')->where('status', ListingStatus::PENDING->value), new Ownership('product', false)],
            'category_id' => ['required', Rule::exists('categories', 'id')->where('is_hidden', false)],
            'product_status' => ['required', 'in:' . implode(',', ProductStatus::toArray()),],
            'title' => ['required', 'max:500'],
            'price' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:0', 'max:1000000'],
            'discount' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'min:0', 'max:100'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:0', 'max:2000'],
            'city_id' => 'nullable|integer|exists:' . Region::class . ',id',
            'state_id' => 'nullable|integer|exists:' . Region::class . ',id',
            'country_id' => 'nullable|integer|exists:' . Region::class . ',id',
            'tags' => ['required', 'array', 'max:10'],
            'tags.*' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'image' => [Rule::requiredIf(empty(request('id'))), 'mimes:jpg,png,jpe,jpeg', 'max:500', 'image'],
            'galleries' => ['array', Rule::requiredIf(empty(request('id'))), 'max:5'],
            'galleries.*' => ['required', 'mimes:jpg,png,jpe,jpeg', 'max:500', 'image'],
            'properties' => ['array', Rule::requiredIf(empty(request('id'))), new ForceProperty()],
            'properties.*.property_id' => ['required',Rule::exists('properties', 'id')],
            'properties.*.property_item_id' => ['required',Rule::exists('property_items', 'id')],
        ];
    }

    public function product($merge, $except = null): array
    {
        return $this->safe()->merge([
            'updater' => auth('sanctum')->id()
        ])->merge($merge)->except('id', 'tags', 'galleries', 'properties', $except);
    }

    public function tags(): array
    {
        return $this->get('tags');
    }

    public function galleries(): array
    {
        return $this->file('galleries');
    }

    public function properties($product_id): array
    {
        return collect($this->get('properties'))->map(function ($value) use ($product_id) {
            $value['product_id'] = $product_id;
            $value['updater'] = auth()->id();
            return $value;
        })->toArray();
    }
```

**ForceValidation**:

```php
class ForceProperty implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(string): PotentiallyTranslatedString  $fail
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        $forceProperties = CategoryProperty::query()->where('is_force', true)->pluck('id','title')->toArray();
        $propertyIds = collect($value)->pluck('property_id')->toArray();
        $missingForceProperties = array_diff($forceProperties, $propertyIds);

        if (!empty($missingForceProperties)) {
            $missingForcePropertyTitles = array_flip($missingForceProperties);
            $fail("Please provide all required properties with IDs: " . implode(', ', $missingForcePropertyTitles));

        }

    }
}
```

I can't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: api requests should have `Accept: application/json` header, otherwise how does Laravel know to respond in json

Comment: you can use `try` and `catch` to see the error,